# How do I find and use new syntax highlighting themes in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, syntax-highlighting

I have installed Visual Studio 2017. I would like to change the colours it uses to do syntax highlighting without changing the GUI colours, and I would like:

- more than what's offered under *Tools/Options/Environment/General/Color theme*
- not to have to manually change dozens of settings manually myself

Searching the web for this just gives me instructions on how to create my own UI theme, and nothing at all on using syntax themes that others have created. Searching the *Online* section of *Extensions and Updates* just gives me new syntax packs. Where can I obtain more syntax highlighting themes, and how do I install them?

Comment: Microsoft has [an add-in](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ColorThemesforVisualStudio) in the gallery.  Luke Sampson created a [dedicated site](https://studiostyl.es/schemes) with too many too choose from.

Comment: @HansPassant Studio Styles doesn't have themes for VS 2017. That add in is useful though, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I manage this myself, hope it helps.

Any setting available under *Tool* -> *Options* and others can be imported and exported using the "Import and Export Settings Wizard" (including syntax highlighting). The wizard is available under *Tools* -> *Import and Export Settings*.

To save your syntax highlighting settings for a given language, open the Import and Export settings wizard and select the relevant items from the list, e.g.:

[image: Import Settings]

This will generate a file with the extension *.vssettings containing your syntax highlighting settings that you can import in other Visual Studio installations.

**Where can I obtain more syntax highlighting themes?**

You can try by searching for .vssettings files in github:

https://github.com/search?q=vssettings

Here is a cool one I found there:

https://draculatheme.com/visual-studio/

Personally, I just look for them using a Web search engine, I don't know of any central repository for this.

**Edit**

Here is a theme generator for VS as pointed out by the OP: https://dainty.site/vs

Comment: Nice! Most of the ones I've found via web searches were for VS 2015 or earlier, and don't work well on VS 2017. The Github search allows me to see which are updated more recently.

Comment: The Github search was a dead-end, most of them are just some random developer's backup settings. But searching Google for "vssettings 2017" led me to find [Dainty](https://dainty.site/vs) which is an excellent theme generator for VS 2017 and a few other Windows dev tools.

Comment: Thanks! I added that to the answer too.